# How would Blockchain technologies change to survive a post-quantum world?

Tags: cryptography, cryptocurrency

Reading [this](https://hackernoon.com/how-i-cornered-the-bitcoin-mining-market-using-a-quantum-computer-9e5dceba9f92) entertaining piece of a QC enthusiast mining bitcoins with a Quantum Computer (although efficiently mining bitcoins with the current state of QCs is far-fetched, it is quite possible to be done in the next few years), I wonder how exactly will technologies already using Blockchain adapt to the change?

Are they currently being worked upon? **How would post-quantum cryptography integrate with existing tech secured using today's cryptography algorithms?**

Comment: One of the most interesting algorithms and relatively easy to implement as it's solely based on hash functions is the BPQS (Blockchained Post-Quantum Signatures) family of protocols, see here https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/658

Answer (score 7):

Bitcoin uses elliptic-curve cryptography to sign transactions, which can easily be broken by Shor's algorithm.

I didn't actually read the article because it looked kind of dumb, but I gathered that the author proposed using Grover's algorithm to speed up the mining process by looking for hashes more efficiently. If you had a functioning quantum computer, then I think it would be more efficient to forget about mining and instead just transfer people's bitcoins directly into your own account. A useful quantum computer would completely destroy the entire Bitcoin fundamental model.

I believe that other cryptocurrencies, like Cardano, are already designed to be secure against quantum attacks, to prevent this issue.