# Time-bin encoding qudits

Tags: resource-request, quantum-state, photonics

> Time-bin encoding is a technique used in Quantum information science to encode a qubit of information on a photon.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-bin_encoding)

Is there a generalization for $n$-th level qudits?

Comment: This question seems to broad.  Are there specific parts of the Wikipedia entry which you don't understand/you have questions about?  Also, why do you link to an article which does **not** use time-bin encoding to encode a 10-level system?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I have narrowed the question. Also, the linked article was meant as an example of a (frequency-bin?) photonic qudit.

Comment: this is a bit confusing. "Time-bin encoding" means to use the time as degree of freedom on which to store the (quantum) information. As such, this sort of encoding can in principle encode arbitrary high-dimensional qudits. The limitation is obviously in the actual experimental constraints.

Comment: @glS Do you have any references regarding encoding arbitrary high-dimensional qudits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! The first application of time bin photonic qudits that comes to mind is for quantum key distribution. Here's an example: https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.01139. I am sure there are more references out there though!

Comment: Awesome! Have you seen this [other question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/2366/2645) of mine?

Answer (score 2):

There is a number of groups using time-bin encoding to realise computation/communication protocols.

One example is Furusawa's group in Japan, which among other things works on measurement-based QC with time-bin encoding (e.g. [1706.06312](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.06312)).
Another example that comes to mind is Silberhorn's group in Paderborn. They use time-bin encoding for various things, a random example of which is [1710.06103](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.06103).